# Exception in thread "png-cruncher_x"

Tags: android, jenkins, aapt

I have set up my Android project on Jenkins and it's working most of the time. But from time to time the build can't complete.

The stacktrace gives me this :

```
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_1" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:104)
at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:107)
at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:204)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

And this exception repeats like 20 times, with "png-cruncher_2", "png-cruncher_8", "png-cruncher_4", "png-cruncher_3"... and then nothing.

I used to abort the build manually and finally configured the job to abort after 10 minutes. If I launch the build again, it usually works.

I upgraded build tools version (currently 22.0.1) but it didn't help. Builds are working fine on my computer so I guess it comes from the server where Jenkins is running, but I can't figure out what's wrong.

Does anyone have any idea what the problem could be ?

EDIT : Jenkins is installed on a PC with Windows

Comment: Edited question, because the only other solution existing is for Linux.

Comment: Did you try setting the environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds?

Comment: No, I did not. Unfortunately I have no idea where this variable comes from and I couldn't find any information about it.